# Limiting Firestore reads and preventing users from abusing onSnapshot listeners?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to safely implement a realtime web UI using Firestore, with a list of items that can dynamically change (add/remove/modify). I am using an onSnapshot listener with a query that has a limit and offset:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "entries"),
  limit(10),
  offset(0)
);
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    this.entries[change.newIndex] = change.doc.data()
  });
});
```

I have a Firestore security rule: `match list: if query.limit <= 10`, but I have concerns:

- Is there a way to dynamically update offset, limit, etc. in the query? If not, changing the offset by 1 in a lazy loaded list would result in 10 additional reads when only 1 is needed.
- Can a user bypass the `query.limit` rule by having multiple onSnapshot listeners, each listening to 10 documents, effectively doubling the reads?
- Are there any security rules that prevent a user from spamming reads within allowed limits? If not, how can I limit users to listening to a specific number of documents on a collection at any given moment?

Is my understanding correct, and what would be the best solution to limit users' reads and prevent abuse of onSnapshot listeners?

Answer (score 1):

Do no know the logic and the final result you are trying to achieve.
I will try to help and I will asume you are using React so: with hardcoded limit and offset you can hurt the user experience I will advice you to read through pagination docs of Firestore and store offset in useState to memorize last offset applied.

Also if you want to ensure the onSnapshot is not abused you can put it in useEffect which is loading only once 1.

```
useEffect(() => {
const q = query(collection(db, "entries"), limit(10), offset(0));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    entries[change.newIndex] = change.doc.data();
  });
});
return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

also you can store the changes in useState like:

```
setState(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
```

Above code will load only once when the component is loaded and then it will listen for updates on the query which is set, every time document field is updated it will set new changes automatically to the state. The return at the end will be triggered before the component is dispatched (page is closed) and will terminate the listener connection.

Comment: How I build the UI is irrelevant in my question. The example code I gave was merely a starting point to lead to the actual problem: it seems that a malicious actor is capable of executing large numbers of reads with currently available Firestore security rule features from a client, in ways that the UI has not intended, and there is no obvious way of solving that with Firestore and Firestore security rules that I can think of.

Comment: Here I think our understandings are differentiating a little bit, usually the UI is the first line of security for normal user, setting the limits what they are allowed to do. On to the concerns from your initial question you can track request made by each user and limit them to some time interval. I hope you figure it out! Good luck!

Comment: I agree, I was thinking I will probably have to implement some time based throttling for reads/writes to prevent abuse. I'm not sure how that is possible with onSnapshot listeners though, as throttling those will almost definitely break anything that uses realtime updates